# Why does this two line program NullPointerException?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Object> someMethod = new Func<Object>(((Object)null).ToString);
        String nameOfMethod = someMethod.Method.Name;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the body of the *someMethod* function ever executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code compiles to a `ldnull` followed by a `ldvirtftn` instruction.  From ECMA-335 for `ldvirtftn` (4.18):

> System.NullReferenceException is
>   thrown if object is null.

You're not calling ToString, but the `ldvirtftn` instruction attempts to load the function pointer to ToString onto the evaluation stack.  To do so, it needs a valid object reference.

Comment: So let's say I rewrote the code to be new Object().  It seems like I would be stuck if Object didn't happen to have a public constructor.  What could we do in this case?

Comment: The problem in this particular case is that ToString is a virtual method (hence why ldvirtftn is used instead of ldftn).  The CLR needs the reference to the object to be able to return a pointer to the actual ToString depending on what was overridden in the class hierarchy.  Even if you did this trick for a non-virtual method, Func's constructor would throw because it checks for null on the instance passed into it.  The bottom line is that if you want to construct a delegate to an instance method, you need a non-null reference.

Comment: @Dejas: so to sum up: you'd have to somehow arrive at an instance of the type to be able to construct a delegate to an instance method.  A null reference won't work because of the reasons I listed in my previous comment.

Comment: that makes sense.  I'm only looking for the string name, but someMethod.Method gives me a lot more.  I see how that structure would depend on the runtime type and as such would require a real instance.

Answer (score 5):

```
Func<Object> someMethod = new Func<Object>(((Object)null).ToString);
```

It's not executing, but you try to access the *method* `ToString()` on a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

(Object) null is still just null. You are trying to call null.ToString() which is why you are getting the NullPointerException.

Comment: Technically, the code does not attempt to call ToString but pass it as a function pointer to Func<T>'s (object, IntPtr) constructor.